# c# winforms - how to make a DataGridViewRow UnSelectable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to prevent user to select cells in a particular dgvRow.
Row is ReadOnly, but still - selectable.

Comment: Maybe javascript to prevent user clicking on it... Anyway, what's the logic behind this decision? Cause you know, everything that has been published on the internet, it can be copied and shared, whatever you do. If you forbid users to click on it (and copy & paste), the user can still access the source code and do whatever he/she wants with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom delegate that unselects the cells in question whenever the selection is changed.

```
DataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(DataGridView1_SelectionChanged);
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    List<DataGridViewCell> toBeRemoved = new List<DataGridViewCell>();
    foreach(DataGridViewCell selectedCell in DataGridView1.SelectedCells){
        if (isCellUnSelectable(selectedCell))
            toBeRemoved.Add(selectedCell);
    }
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in toBeRemoved){
        cell.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe that dgv has no such a builtIn property. AnyWay, thanks to both.

Comment: dgv has no way of creating this property because the contents of the dgv is dynamically allocated, meaning it has no static handles on given cells. If you try to add a cell and make it unselectable, dgv has to be designed around that cell being deleted and another similar one readded, which makes keeping track of properties like selectable for individual cells impractical.